# VS2013 Agents from where can i download?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, tfs, agents

**VS2013 agents** are not found in site https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=40750,where can i download it from.I want it to install in build server to run unit test from TFS xaml build.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to download the TFS 2013 ISO, run the installation, and the configure the build controller and agents.

You can find the TFS 2013 ISO by going [here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=team%20foundation%20server%202013) and then selecting "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 with Update 5".

Installation and configuration instructions can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259687(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: The download link is not available..can you please check and give me the link.

Comment: That's odd...  I just tested the link with an incognito tab and it worked.  Anyways, go to [https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads](https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads), log in, search for "Team Foundation Server 2013" and select "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 with Update 5"

Comment: Is there any other way to run NUnit Test from XAML build?

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to use the XAML builds, but I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254538/how-to-run-nunit-tests-using-a-template-in-tfs-build-server) might help.  It's a lot easier with the non-xaml based builds in the newer versions of TFS.